# Storyboard Random Matching Views

Tags: ios

I have a view controller with a few buttons, labels and 2 views. One view is a background. The other is a puzzle on top of it. Everything is in perfect working order. I know how to randomly create the puzzles keeping just one background. What I want to do is hit a button and have a new puzzle with its matching background. I want all other functions on the page to stay the same. Just a new puzzle with it's matching background. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need more information, like code for the IBOutlet button and screenshots. Also it's not explained in the question what your title means, "matching random views"?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry. Using storyboard I want to match my puzzle image with a background view randomly. Let's say I have 1,000 different puzzle images. I want to match 1,000 puzzle images with 1,000 backgrounds. I hit a button and a new random puzzle with the matching background will appear. I need to use 2 views because the code for the puzzle is for a pic. I don't want the background turned into a puzzle. Also I just want those 2 views to change because there are other buttons and labels that I want to keep their properties. As for screenshots and code, I'll do that when I get to my computer.

Comment: A specific puzzle has to have the specific matching background for that puzzle. So, I need a matching pair of views to show up randomly using storyboard or whatever else I need to use. How can this be done?

Comment: Code for which button? As of right now I just have a shuffle button and a button that shows what the puzzle looks like solved. I know what to do to create random puzzles. I haven't put that in or any other images yet because I already know that is not what I need to do. I need to know how to pair 2 views (the puzzle view and the background view) and have them pulled up randomly when I hit the new button that I create for a new puzzle.

Answer (score 0):

*I'll leave the details of the implementation for you to fill in.*

You need to be able to correlate your views. You can do this with strictly-managed arrays or with simple composition objects or with direct relationship.

**strictly-managed arrays**

```
NSArray *puzzles = @[/*...*/];
NSArray *backgrounds = @[/*...*/];

- (IBAction)changePuzzle {
  NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform([puzzles count]);
  UIView *puzzleView = puzzles[index];
  UIView *backgroundView = backgrounds[index];
  // Update UI with puzzleView and backgroundView
}
```

**simple composition object**

```
@interface MatchedView : NSObject
@property (strong) UIView *puzzle;
@property (strong) UIView *background;
@end

NSArray *matchedViews = @[/*...*/];

- (IBAction)changePuzzle {
  NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform([matchedViews count]);
  UIView *puzzleView = [matchedView[index] puzzleView];
  UIView *backgroundView = [matchedView[index] backgroundView];
  // Update UI with puzzleView and backgroundView
}
```

**direct relationship**

```
@interface PuzzleView : UIView
@property (strong) UIView *backgroundView;
/* ... */
@end

NSArray *puzzleViews = @[/*...*/];

- (IBAction)changePuzzle {
  NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform([puzzleViews count]);
  PuzzleView *puzzleView = puzzleViews[index];
  UIView *backgroundView = [puzzleView backgroundView];
  // Update UI with puzzleView and backgroundView
}
```

---

Make those IBOutlets as you see fit. You can replace the array in any of those cases with any other way that you have to look up the views you want to randomly choose among (i.e. using `tag`).